# How to not have a "/" character in a hashed string?

Tags: hashcode, fragment-identifier, reset-password

I am trying to generate a reset password link for my web application and have thought of hashing timestamp+useremail+password with a secret string and then the hashed string would be unique for each user who wants to reset their password.

But the problem is that these hashed strings have the "/" character in them at times, and so if I use these strings, then the link won't work properly. How do I avoid this problem? Which hashing technique or what else should I use for generating my links?

Comment: Hash them and replace the `/` with another character? Or hash them and remove all occurences of `/`.  Another option is to hash then encode in a URL safe Base64

Comment: If I do that,suppose replace "/" with "]", when I try to decode the link in server side, I won't know how many "]" were originally "/" and how many are part of the userEmail and hashed password.

Comment: how about the last option, convert to URL safe Base64, then you can convert it back later on.

Comment: Great, thanks. I will try it.